# Is it necessary to memorize every line of code when it comes to game development?

Tags: java, programming-practices, game-development

I am currently following along a youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98eOOCk2fOFg7Qg5yoQfFAdf) and from what I understand we are starting out by creating an engine to run the game. Should I be able to implement all of this by myself without outside help in the future or should I just make sure to have an understanding of everything that is going on? Would a professional game developer know how to implement everything that it takes to make a game or would he/she just copy and paste certain parts (like creating a buffer, or fps cap) and edit it to their taste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how well you want to understand the process.

As a matter of general principle, you should never re-invent any wheel, unless you either

1. Think you can do it better than the experts, or
2. Are doing it for the learning experience.

If your goal is to get a game released as quickly and economically as possible, you should leverage the work of others as much as you possibly can, subject to monetary and licensing restraints.

If your goal is to learn as much as you can, and getting a game released is of secondary importance, then by all means... re-invent everything.

**A note about Encapsulation**
The reason that libraries are possible (and you don't have to understand their inner workings to utilize them) is due to the abstraction we call Encapsulation.  Abstractions like encapsulation allow us to build a black box that works, without being overly concerned about what is happening under the hood.  This is a good thing; if we had to remember how everything in a software system works, we'd quickly outstrip our mental abilities.

Comment: I'd also note on the "memorizing" bit. You don't need to memorize a lot, really. Instead you should be able to reproduce the results by understanding the topic.

Comment: There's also an article I've seen a few years ago that may clarify many things for you, and prevent you from falling on one of the greatest pitfalls of game development: http://scientificninja.com/blog/write-games-not-engines

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn’t necessary to remember every line of code.  I am not a game developer but my advice is to be more concerned about the overall design and structure of a project.  Plenty of developers reuse existing code, in one form or another - there’s no shame in that. *BUT*, copying and pasting code - without even attempting to understand how it works - isn’t the way to go.

As the other poster has indicated "re-inventing the wheel” can either be a great waste of time (especially if the result is no better or worse) or a great learning experience - it depends on your goals.